# How to cancel $interval Method without ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

Actually I Need to Fire `$http` call to get the data for every **5 Seconds** From One Controller.

I need to Cancel the Interval in the Other Controller .

Code Follows :-

Controller 1(Find all Events):-

```
function($interval,$timeout) {

        $rootScope.strtFinding=true;

         var FireItUpAndFindEvents=$interval(function(){
           console.log('$rootScope.strtFinding'+$rootScope.strtFinding);
         },5000);


        if($rootScope.strtFinding === false){ 
           console.log('$rootScope.strtFinding'+$rootScope.strtFinding);
            $scope.stop();
        };

        $scope.stop=function(){
            console.log('Called the Finding event');
            $interval.cancel(FireItUpAndFindOrders);
        };
```

Controller 2:-

```
 $rootscope.strtFinding=false;
```

Here I am Facing a challenge to Cancel the `$interval` from Other Controller By Updating `$rootScope`.

Please let me know Ideas .. Help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Make a function in a service to set the timer and inject the service to both controllers.I think there is also a way to inject controllers to each other but I have never done that.  In addition there is only a single character difference between `strtFinding` and `startFinding` yet one of them is significantly easier to read. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

You could write a service for this as mentioned in the comments or use events `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast`.

Difference between these two. Emitting goes from childs up to `$rootScope` and broadcasting goes down e.g. from `$rootScope` to all children.

At start button click I emit an event with the interval promise and the other controller can bind a method on `$rootScope` so it detects starting the interval.

Stopping can then be done with the promise passed with the event. But we need to `$broadcast` a stop event after stopping the interval so the `StartController` can clear the promise variable otherwise another start after stop wouldn't be possible.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/y5qh2Lu6/).

**Update 10.10.2015**

As you mentioned in the comments your use-case is different than what I coded and stopping an interval with changing to a different controller is easier than the event stuff.

Add your counter to ´$rootScope´ to have it displayed even after route change. I think otherwise the value would be destroyed with your controller.

Then pass your promise to your new state as `stateParams` so you can stop the interval. That should also work for `ngRoute` but then it should be done with `$routeParams`.

I'm hiding the stop button if the interval is not started to avoid the code to check if there is a promise.

You can find the demo with `ui.router` in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zL4bbgn2/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('TimerController', TimerController)
 .controller('StopController', StopController);

function TimerController($scope, $interval) {
    var self = this,
        intPromise;
    
    $scope.$on('timerEvent:stopped', function() {
     intPromise = null; // timer stopped in other controller
    });
    
 this.start = function() {
        if (!intPromise) {
      intPromise = $interval(update, 1000);
         $scope.$emit('timerEvent:start', intPromise);
        }
    }
    
    function update() {
     self.value = Math.round(Math.random()*100, 0);
    }     
}

function StopController($rootScope, $interval) {
 var self = this;
    
    $rootScope.$on('timerEvent:start', function(evt, promise) {
        console.log(promise);
     self.timerPromise = promise;
    });
    
    this.stop = function() {
        console.log('stoppin', self.timerPromise);
        if ( self.timerPromise ) {
      $interval.cancel(self.timerPromise);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('timerEvent:stopped');
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="TimerController as timerCtrl">
        <button ng-click="timerCtrl.start()">start</button>
        {{timerCtrl.value}}
    </div>
    
    <div ng-controller="StopController as stopCtrl">
        <button ng-click="stopCtrl.stop()">stop</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ AWOLF I saw your Fiddle which is Good with  ng-clicks. But the Challenging One  I need is to Stop the Timer without Firing a ng-click . I need to Cancel the timer When i changed  From ctrl 1 to Other controller SO Rootscope Plays the trick  . Could You pls Modify Code Regarding that Scenario Plz.

Comment: Ah OK, that should be possible too. What router are you using? `ngRoute` or `ui.router`? Just to make the demo for your router.

Comment: That's possible. Please have a look at my updated answer. Is it like you need it? I had another idea: Adding the promise of the interval to `$rootScope` would probably work, too. But I think the way with `$stateParams` is cleaner. But creating a service for your `$interval` would be the best approach. Then you could call a stop method from your `stopController`.

Comment: Let me Give you A REAL Scenario . Users place orders frm Ordering Link . But when i go to another state lets say Store Stock then the background Music(Ajaxcall for every 5 Sec ) should Not happen .. Please Provide a fiddle or something with your idea. I Would take a look my post morning Time. You gave me more ideas Mr.Awolf . i can give you Good Rep frm my side my morning. Plz Provide Fiddle something if you can .. Nice Day !! Wolf

Comment: $rootScope.watch does the trick mate .. you can upvote if my post is informative  Good Day !!